# how to hide a div tag element on mobile view of site

Tags: html, css

See the website http://www.localjobpool.com
I would like to hide the green top bar in mobi
le view.
Staring code of div tag is:

```
<div id="info">
    <div class="menuHolder">

    </div>
</div>
```

menuHolder and nav are defined in my custom CSS. I tried the solution like
@media screen......

like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .info .menuHolder .nav {
        display: none
    }    
}
```

Please tell me how I can hide this bar in mobile view. And where should I insert the code suggested by you...

Comment: Try this link if it helps [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

That should work...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.menuHolder{
display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 .menuHolder {display:none;}
}
```

also info is id and not class ( #info .menuHolder )

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#info .menuHolder{
display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this media query, it should target all tablets and smartphones. Maybe you can modify its values to adjust to your needs:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
  only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
  only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {

    .info .menuHolder .nav {
      display: none;
    }

}
```

Or the same devices, only on landscape:

```
 @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (orientation : landscape),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10) and (orientation : landscape),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) and (orientation : landscape) {

      .info .menuHolder .nav {
        display: none;
      }

}
```

Worked perfectly for me.

Source: https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599